# Node await Promise.all() to be fully resolved

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I'm working with promises and I need to know the result of all the items processed by an async method. So I thought that a Promise.all() would solve my problem like this:

```
const values = await Promise.all(items.map((item) => {
  asyncMethodThatLogsAndReturnsBoolean(item);
}));

console.log(values);
```

What I find here is that some logs of the async method are printed after the values log. And `values` is printed as an array of `undefined`.

Is there any reason why this implementation is not waiting until all promises are resolved so the values object can be printed with the correct data?

*The `asyncMethodThatLogsAndReturnsBoolean(item)` calls other async methods, but all calls have `await`.

Comment: `items.map(item => asyncMethodThatLogsAndReturnsBoolean(item))` should do it.

Comment: Consider using https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return ESlint rule to avoid this sort of mistakes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The callback function inside `map` needs to return a promise.

```
const values = await Promise.all(items.map((item) => {
  return asyncMethodThatLogsAndReturnsBoolean(item);
}));
```

Otherwise, by not explicitly returning anything, you're only returning `undefined`, which has `Promise.all` assume that the element in the mapped array has successfully "resolved" to `undefined`, which is not what you intended.